# Finding the proportionality constant in $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}A_\mu^{\ \lambda} A_\nu^{\ \rho}\propto \varepsilon^{\lambda\rho}$

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

We can show that the contraction of some arbitrary $2\times2$ matrix $A_{\mu}^{\ \lambda}$ with the Levi-Civita symbol is once again antisymmetric
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}A_\mu^{\ \lambda} A_\nu^{\ \rho}  = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}\left(A_{\mu}^{\ \lambda} A_{\nu}^{\ \rho} - A_{\nu}^{\ \lambda} A_{\mu}^{\ \rho}\right)
\end{align*}
where we basically just replaced $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$ in the second term and used the antisymmetry of the Levi-Civita. Now the RHS has two free indices $\lambda, \rho$ and it's antisymmetric wrt to those. So I believe it should be possible to write it as $C \varepsilon^{\lambda \rho}$. I struggle, however, to find $C$. I don't see how it's possible to strip off the free indices and combine them in a new Levi-Civita. I tried playing around with raising and lowering the indices, but my best guess so far lead me to a product of uncontracted Minkowski metrics
$$
\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}A_\mu^{\ \lambda} A_\nu^{\ \rho} = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu} A_{\mu\alpha} A_{\nu\beta}\left(\eta^{\alpha\lambda}\eta^{\beta\rho} - \eta^{\alpha\rho} \eta^{\beta\lambda}\right)
$$
which I don't know how to simplify further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standard [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Two_dimensions_2) of the tensor in solving for *C*,
$$
\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}A_\mu^{\ \lambda} A_\nu^{\ \rho}  = C \varepsilon^{\lambda\rho} ~~~~~\leadsto \\
\epsilon _{\lambda \rho} \varepsilon^{\mu\nu}A_\mu^{\ \lambda} A_\nu^{\ \rho}  =\epsilon _{\lambda \rho}  C \varepsilon^{\lambda\rho} ~~~~~\implies \\
   A_\mu^{~\mu } A_\nu^{~\nu } -A_\mu^{~\nu } A_\nu^{~\mu } = 2 C .
$$

Answer (score 1):

The properties of the epsilon tensor (as exploited by Cosmas Zachos) give a very elegant answer here. But, if you didn't know about those identities, you can still get the answer in a straightforward and systematic way. When you are stuck in a situation like this, don't be afraid to actually just write out components.

\begin{eqnarray}
\epsilon^{\mu\nu} A_\mu^0 A_\nu^0 &=& A^0_0 A^0_1 - A^0_1 A^0_0 = 0\\
\epsilon^{\mu\nu} A_\mu^1 A_\nu^1 &=& A^1_0 A^1_1 - A^1_1 A^1_0 = 0\\
\epsilon^{\mu\nu} A_\mu^1 A_\nu^0 &=& A^1_0 A^0_1 - A^1_1 A^0_0 = C \\
\epsilon^{\mu\nu} A_\mu^0 A_\nu^1 &=& A^0_0 A^1_1 - A^0_1 A^1_0 = -C
\end{eqnarray}
Then we do some fiddling to write the answer into a manifestly Lorentz invariant form
\begin{eqnarray}
C &=& A^1_0 A^0_1 - A^1_1 A^0_0 \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( A^0_0 A^0_0 + A^0_1 A^1_0 + A^1_0 A^0_1 + A^1_1 A^1_1 - A^0_0 A^0_0 - 2 A^0_0 A^1_1 - A^1_1 A^1_1 \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( A^\mu_\nu A^\nu_\mu - (A^\mu_\mu)^2 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Since this is a pretty simple problem and I have some experience, I was able to do the above calculation efficiently just by guessing. But in a more complicated case, or if you want something more systematic, you could use a version of this argument: you know that the final answer has to be Lorentz invariant. There are only two possible scalars you can make out of an expression of the form $A^2$: $A^\mu_\nu A^\nu_\mu$ and $(A^\mu_\mu)^2$. So you can simply introduce two free parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and then write
\begin{eqnarray}
C &=& A^1_0 A^0_1 - A^1_1 A^0_0 \\
&=& \alpha A^\mu_\nu A^\nu_\mu + \beta (A^\mu_\mu)^2 \\
&=& 2 \alpha A^1_0 A^0_1 + 2 \beta A^1_1 A^0_0 + \left(\alpha+\beta\right) \left[(A^0_0)^2 + (A^1_1)^2\right]
\end{eqnarray}
Then matching the first and third lines, you'll find $\alpha=-\beta=\frac{1}{2}$.